# Это ошибка или я смог подключить к БД?

Tags: python, mysql

После запуска получаю в консоли следующие строки:

> (<mysql.connector.cursor_cext.CMySQLCursor object at 0x000001C5944CB490>, <mysql.connector.connection_cext.CMySQLConnection object at 0x000001C591046890>)

Я не понимаю, это ошибка или я смог подключить к БД?

```
def connection():
try :
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost",
            user = 'root',
            password = '',
            database = 'diss',
            port = '3306',
            auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
    c = conn.cursor()
    return c , conn
except Exception as ex :
        print('2')
        print(ex) 
print('1')
```

Comment: Это ошибка, если хочешь убедиться в этом, убери `except Exception as ex` , тогда выведется полноценное сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Табуляции исправьте и предоставьте код, соответствующий выводу. И весь вывод, а не кусочек.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему у вас представленный код не соответствует тому, что вы запускаете. Поэтому приходится гадать.
У вас кортеж из курсора и соединения выводятся в принте.
Дальше работайте с курсором. Переменная c.

И если ничего непонятно, то не надо перехватывать исключения. Вы не даёте и питону вам подсказать.